# Directory layout of categories

Tags: user-behavior

I have an e-commerce site, and my main products page, shows no products, its a starting page to help you find the right categories, or filters, you want to select to start your product search.

I am not that happy with my design though. I have broken up the filters into various categories. Created a box for each category, and labeled the filters in said box. However, I cant think of a nice way to display the filters, whilst still making it obvious they are separated.

This is what I have now

[image]

It does the job, but the filters just dont look beautiful, I want them to look attractive for users to click. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I think the option you're missing is vertical-ness. Filters, for lots of reasons, work better in vertical stacks. Probably the best use of filters, I know of, is hotel booking sites.

**Stars**

- "*****"
- "****"
- "***"
- "**"
- "*"

**Locations**

- Suburb or Region
- Suburb or Region
- Suburb or Region
- Suburb or Region

**Popularity**

- more than 1000
- 750 to 1000
- 500 to 750
- less than 500

**Features**

- Swimming Pool
- Free internet
- Gym
- Valet parking
- Restaurants

Comment: i think you are right, but I also didnt want it to make the page too long. So I could have 3 columns in each box: 1. icon and category title 2. a list of filters 3. a list of the other filters

Answer (score 1):

**Your filters offer too much contrast**

This design would work if you had fewer "filters". The look of a filter offers a high contrast, the problem is that you have too many them, so it is difficult to distinguish them.

> It does the job, but the filters just dont look beautiful, I want them to look attractive for users to click. Any thoughts?

- You can **consider your filters as subcategories** in which case you can list them as links and find a nice way to present them.
- Or maybe they can be **seen as tags**, in which case try to make them look like so.

[image: example of a tag]

Be sure that, if you put too much contrast on multiple objects, nothing will strike out of your page.